# ciclo while con variable aux?

Tags: java, bucles, while

He visto que ocupan una variable que se llama `aux` para los ciclos del `while` cuando quieren repetir el número de veces, por ejemplo, si tengo del **1 al 5** y yo ingreso en el número de consultas 10 me tiene que arrojar **1234512345** por eso se ocupa una variable `aux` para recetar el `while`, ¿Me puden explicar como se utiliza eso?.

**Ejemplo:**

```
int num_pruebas=1;
int aux_pruebas=1;

while(num_pruebas <=num) {
    
if(aux_pruebas==32) {
  aux_pruebas=0;
}

aux_pruebas++;
num_pruebas++;
```

Comment: Debuguea para que te des cuenta

Comment: @Japv y como???

Comment: el código que pusiste ni siquiera compila, deberías de indicarnos que deseas que haga en un [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int num = 64;  
int num_pruebas = 1;
int aux_pruebas = 1;
while( num_pruebas <= num ) {
    System.out.println( aux_pruebas ):
    if( aux_pruebas == 32 ) {
         aux_pruebas = 0;
    }
    aux_pruebas ++;
    num_pruebas ++;
}
```

El funcionamiento es bastante sencillo, las variables, **num** y **num_pruebas**, se usan para limitar la cantidad de iteraciones del bucle, en tanto **aux_pruebas** se usa para "calcular" la salida.
Cuando el bucle comienza, **num_pruebas** y **aux_pruebas** "viajan juntas", osea tienen el mismo valor, cuando se llega a "32", se imprime el valor de **aux_pruebas** y luego entra en el **if**, asignandolé a **aux_pruebas** el valor "0", que luego será aumentado a "1", para, en la próxima iteración imprimir "1", mientras que **num_pruebas** seguirá aumentando hasta legar a "64", momento en el que se sale del bucle.
Probablemente lo veas más claro con un **for**:

```
int aux_pruebas = 1;
for( int num_pruebas = 1; num_pruebas <= 64; num_pruebas++ ) {
    System.out.println( aux_pruebas ):
    if( aux_pruebas == 32 ) {
         aux_pruebas = 0;
    }
    aux_pruebas ++;
}
```

PD 1: Hay muchas formas de conseguir el mismo resultado.
PD 2: inicializo num_pruebas** en "1" solo para respetar el ejemplo que pusiste, lo normal es asignarle un "0".